# Copiar uma colecção MongoDB usando pymongo e colá-la noutra colecção

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

Quero copiar uma colecção `coll` para fazer uma cópia de segurança numa base de dados em MongoDB. Por isso, tentei:

```
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient(
...             f"mongodb+srv://{user}:{password}@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/es_eso_importante?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
>>>
>>> db = client['test']
>>> source = db['coll']
>>> destination = db['coll_backup']
>>> pipeline = [ {"$match": {}},
...              {"$out": "coll_backup"}]
>>> db.coll.aggregate(pipeline)
<pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor object at 0x00000214564785F8>
```

Mas não tenho quaisquer alterações no Atlas MongoDB.

Se houver quaisquer outras alternativas (gratuitas) estou pronto a ouvi-las.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que foi descrito por você seria apenas parte do código

Está faltando algo do tipo:

```
for doc in source: 
    destination.insert(doc)
```

**Nota** Este processo será lento para coleções grandes.

Use o próprio MongoDB. [Este](https://www.mongodbmanager.com/clone-mongodb-collection#:%7E:text=Copy%20Collection%20to%20another%20Database%20is%20a%20professional%20feature%20of,item%20in%20the%20popup%20menu.) é um bom post para saber mais.